# Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении с союзом

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему у автора в предложении перед "и" нет запятой: Все выпускники сейчас стоят на пороге выбора жизненного пути и им очень важно не ошибиться. Можно ли "сейчас" считать общим обстоятельством для простых предложений. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая, безусловно, нужна. Если начать выискивать "общие второстепенные члены" в ССП, то их можно находить(притягивать за уши) почти всюду. Не надо мудрствовать! Одно дело **Вчера было холодно и шёл снег**, и совсем другое – данный пример.

Между прочим, в стихотворении Плещеева тоже запятая.

Comment: Возможно, здесь запятая нужна, но только НЕ БЕЗУСЛОВНО. И объяснение у Вас очень эмоциональное. Представьте себе, что на экзамене абитуриент поясняет  выбор  знаков препинания и обращается к педагогу, используя вашу логику и ваши дословные высказывания.

Answer (score 3):

Да, "сейчас" можно считать общим обстоятельством для простых предложений.

Общий второстепенный член может находиться в середине предложения (запятая не ставится), например:

"Засвищут **скоро** соловьи   и лес оденется листвою".

Comment: _"Засвищут скоро соловьи и лес оденется листвою"._ === Vera, не подскажете,  в каких учебных пособиях рекомендуют **не ставить** запятую в этом предложении?

Comment: Нет, пока не могу найти, но пример точно списан из какого-то пособия. В современных текстах запятая обычно ставится, но иногда встречаются вариант без запятой. Так что вопрос остается открытым: меняли пунктуацию или нет и когда меняли.

Comment: Вера, а вы откуда брали пример?

Comment: _В современных текстах запятая обычно ставится..._ === Но если она **в современных** текстах ставится, то Ваша ссылка на этот пример в ответе некорректна. Нужно найти что-то другое...

Comment: Надо сначала разобраться с этой историей: как было, как стало. Кроме того, я ссылаюсь не на один пример, их предостаточно. И еще очень хотелось бы, чтобы при решении орфографических задач было бы поменьше фанатизма и стремления к математической обязательности. Стараясь соблюсти правила с микроскопической точностью и ничего не выигрывая от этого, мы меньше внимания уделяем действительно важным вещам.

Comment: Vera, напомню Вам Ваши же слова из комментария к ответу Niemand: _"Представьте себе, что на экзамене абитуриент поясняет выбор знаков препинания и обращается к педагогу, используя вашу логику и ваши дословные высказывания"._

Comment: Когда верны оба ответа, то и с педагогом несложно договориться, всё будет зависеть от вашего красноречия. Совершенно беспроигрышный вариант: а абитуриенты целы, и профессор доволен. Вообще говоря, правила должны придавать стройность системе, но при этом не мешать ее творческому самовыражению.

Comment: Вера, никак не смог найти пособие, где сказано, что второстепенный член может находится в середине предложения. Не могли бы вы подсказать, где найти такое пособие?

Comment: Серж, найду по возможности. Я брала материал из собственных конспектов, и тема эта откуда-то списана, но откуда - не могу вспомнить.

Comment: Вера, дело в том, что второстепенный член предложения - дополнение в примерах можно встретить; а вот об-ство или придаточное обстоятельственное предложение со значением места или времени я не встречал в середине.

Comment: Есть у меня такое пособие "Дидактические материалы по пунктуации с компьютерной поддержкой" под ред. проф. Алгазиной, 1998 г

Comment: В нем рассмотрена эта тема и приведены предложения: Всё прекрасное на земле от солнца и всё хорошее от человека (Горький). Ветер к утру ослабел и снег перестал (Павленко). Бродили по ночам вокруг дома караульщики и трещали трещотки. Кстати, обстоятельство можно элементарно переставить, вряд ли от этого изменятся знаки препинания (К утру ветер  ослабел и снег перестал).

Comment: Интересные предложения. В предложениях ''Ветер к утру ослабел и снег перестал'' (Павленко). ''Бродили по ночам вокруг дома караульщики и трещали трещотки''. второс-ый член можно разглядеть - ''к утру'' и '' по ночам''. Но вот в предложении ''Гонятся над лугом друг за другом стрекозы и перепархивают бабочки". хотя и формально можно разглядеть вто-ый член, но в тестах я встретил это предложение с запятой.

Comment: А как только не упражняются с первым предложением Горького, ставят одно тире, два тире и запятую. Кстати предложение "И было душно в ущелье темном и пахло гнилью" тоже по-разному объясняют, например, отсутствие запятой иногда связывают с общим членом, считая односоставные предложения неоднородными.

Answer (score 3):

***Все выпускники сейчас стоят на пороге выбора жизненного пути, и им очень важно не ошибиться.***

Думаю, что в этом предложении запятая перед *и* нужна. Обстоятельство *сейчас* находится посредине первого предложения, и не чувствуется, что оно относится так же ко второму, как к первому (в отличие от слова *скоро* в классическом примере из поэтического текста "Засвищут скоро соловьи и лес оденется листвою"). Второе предложение безличное, в нём утверждается, что выпускникам не именно сейчас, а в принципе важно не ошибиться.

Вот если бы *сейчас* находилось в начале всей конструкции, тогда можно было бы считать это обстоятельство общим второстепенным членом. Ср.: *Сейчас все выпускники  стоят на пороге выбора жизненного пути и им очень важно не ошибиться.*

Comment: При изучении ССП выделяется особая тема: "Общий второстепенный член находится В СЕРЕДИНЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ и поэтому не сразу виден". Поэтому середина предложения не причина для решения. В то же время статус общего члена - это часто авторский выбор. Думаю, что распространенность предложений и их разная структура может склонять автора к постановке запятой. Возможно, здесь следует сказать, что оба варианта допускаются.

Comment: Простите, но я не говорила, что середина предложения - "причина для решения". В этом конкретном случае обстоятельство, находясь не в начале, а в середине,  как бы теряется в составе первого предложения и почти не влияет на второе. К тому же второе предложение - безличное. Я за запятую.

Comment: Я приведу несколько примеров, где общее слово может "теряться". "Чужды вам страсти   и чужды страдания. Взгляд его был умным   и в голосе звучала сила. Голова у него болела, гудело в ушах и во всём теле чувствовалось недомогание. Губы Кати не улыбались и глаза выражали недоумение. Ветер к утру ослабел   и снег престал. Гонятся над лугом друг за другом стрекозы   и перепархивают бабочки".   Поэтому я за авторское решение.

Answer (score 1):

Можно было бы считать "скоро" общим обстоятельством, если бы не логическая связь простых предложений. Если "соловьи и лес" синхронизируются со временем наступления весны, а не между собой, то здесь иная картина. Важно не ошибиться не потому, что приходит пора не ошибаться, а потому, что грядёт ответственный выбор (обозначено время его появления) и не ошибиться нужно **в нём**. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Alex_ander, мы почти каждый день что-либо выбираем и часто делаем не лучший выбор, но существует особые МОМЕНТЫ, когда не ошибиться особенно важно.  Об этом  "сейчас" и идет речь в предложении. Выпускникам именно сейчас важно не ошибиться, поэтому "сейчас" относится ко второму предложению тоже.

Comment: Здесь "важность не ошибиться" относится к тому же времени, но не напрямую, а через смысл первого предложения: скоро надо будет выбирать; (в этом выборе) важно не ошибиться.

Comment: Alex_ander, если б мы так рассудочно строили предложения, то, наверное, разучились бы говорить (шутка). Ваш собеседник или читатель вряд ли будет анализировать такие сложные логические связи, которые вы предлагаете ему увидеть.

Comment: Я не то чтобы предлагаю ему увидеть связи, а пытаюсь "препинанием" отвлечь его от идеи привязать ко времени редко случающийся период уклонения от ошибок - с тем, чтобы он пришёлся на "порог выбора" :)

Comment: Кажется, Гете говорил о том, что люди понимают друг друга только потому, что говорят быстро, не вдумываясь в значение каждого конкретного слова, а  вы хотите, чтобы они вдумывались в запятые. Вообще говоря, идея общего члена в ССП, как мне кажется, не очень понимается пользователями, которые преувеличивают его значение. Не ставить запятую желательно в тех случаях, когда  предложения составляют единую интонационно-структурную единицу  и пауза между ними явно нежелательна. В других же вариантах лучше предоставить автору решать этот вопрос.

Comment: Я бы скорее нарушил правила и не поставил запятую в недавнем "Я милая и у меня красивые ноги" - лучше дополнить десяток исключений, недосочинённый к тому правилу - раз уж формально нельзя к имеющимся исключениям подвести этот случай "по совокупности" (общий производитель действия, подчинённость общему смыслу и пр.)". В целом, я противник лишних запятых и культа "двусторонних" обособлений, от которых возникает чудовищная запятая после "и", которая всегда мешает читать: ведь не ради расчленения на обороты текст пишется :)

Comment: Сложно работать с одним предложением, когда не видишь текста, органичной частью которого оно является. Помните: - Свой талант у всех... - У вас? - Два-с: Умеренность и аккуратность. Здесь речь примерно о том же.